# WPF databinding to ObservableCollection - ItemTemplate not changing displayed value

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I'm trying to get databinding on a WPF `ListView` to work correctly however for whatever reason, it will always use the value provided by `ToString` regardless what I've tried.

As is, I have something like the following:

```
private Controllers.ListController controller;
public ListTest( )
{
    // ...
    listView.DataContext = controller;
}
private void Page_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var t = new Task( ( ) =>
    {
        // some work to obtain data using controller...
        Dispatcher.Invoke( ( ) =>
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = controller.TestListSource;
        } );
    } );

    t.Start( );
}
```

This successfully binds the `ListView` to the data provided by the controller and the list view will show every entry inside the `IEnumerable<TestListEntry>`. The problem is, I can't seem to change how the `ListView` shows each row. `TestListEntry` is as follows:

```
public class TestListEntry
{
    public string GivenName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string FamilyName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ FamilyName }, { GivenName }";
        }
    }
}
```

I initially tried to set `ListBox.ItemTemplate` like so:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="listView">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="test" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

However this doesn't change anything. Having WPF binding debugging turned on too shows nothing in regards to an error too, does show something seemingly irrelevant though

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

I also tried to set a background colour on the `TextBlock` inside `ItemTemplate` and it didn't change anything either, so not sure what's going on there. I then tried to set `DisplayNamePath` and `SelectedValuePath`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="researcherListView" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" SelectedValuePath="DisplayName">
```

which didn't change anything either. I know I could change `ToString` to get around this issue but I have a feeling I'm just missing something...

Comment: @mm8 yeah, it does. It's implemented as a `ObservableCollection<TestListEntry>` though

Comment: I tested your code using the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` and it works perfectly. Do you have any implicit styles or templates set for `ListBox`, `TextBlock` or `TestListEntry`? (That would also explain the `System.Windows.Data Information` messages.) If not, please isolate the problem and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can find the culprit.

Comment: @haindl apologies, I was setting `ListView.View` and forgot to include it in my answer. Which can be fixed by setting `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}"` - why is that? Does each column inherit their binding from `ListView.View`s `GridViewColumn` if you set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `<GridView>` in the `<ListView.View>` you need to tell the `<GridViewColumn>` how to display its content of `TestListEntry` in the generated cells. If you don't, then `.ToString()` is the only possible way because that's the only information every object has.
Using the `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` just isn't enough because it doesn't know anything about the specific columns.

To control the displayed content you can either set the binding directly, like you mentioned in your comment:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="test" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
```

Or you can set the `<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>` using your `<DataTemplate>`:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="test">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Using a `<DataTemplate>` would surely be the better solution if you want to style your cells a bit more than just displaying the text.